# React Native - Stack Navigator inside Drawer Navigator inside Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I have some troubles while mixing different navigators.
Here is my navigator file :

```
const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
})

const TabNav = TabNavigator({
    Drawers: { screen: DrawerNav },
    Params: { screen: Params },
    Search: { screen: Search },
},
{
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
});

export default StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: TabNav },
}, stackNavigatorConfig);
```

The problems are when I open the Drawer Navigator :

- The first tab lose the tabBarIcon and the tabBarLabel configuration from the "Drawers" container (which is set in Screen1). The icon disappear, and the label becomes "Drawers" (the Name in the TabNavigator declaration) instead of the original tabBarLabel value set in the
- The Header of the Stack Navigator is still visible above the Drawer, and lose the style I have set in the Screen1 navigationOptions. (for this one, I can eventually remove the Stack Navigator and create my own header, its was just faster to use the Stack Navigator)

Here is two images with the different states (drawer closed / opened) :

[image: Drawer closed]

[image: Drawer open]

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you are using a drawer inside a tab.

In order to be able to navigate through all the app the drawer must be included in the stack:

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
        Params: { screen: Params },
        Search: { screen: Search },
    },
    {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    }
);

const DrawerNav = DrawerNavigator({
    Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
    Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
    TabNav: { screen: TabNav },
})

export default StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: TabNav },
    DrawerNav: { screen: DrawerNav }
}, stackNavigatorConfig);
```

In the other hand, if what you are looking for is to fire the drawer through a click on that tab, you need to hack the tab from the source, or fire a function  when that empty screen render that make a call to:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen'); // open drawer
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose'); // close drawer
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerToggle'); // fires 'DrawerOpen'/'DrawerClose' accordingly
```

I hope that help..

Comment: The drawer is only used on the first tab, that's why I have the drawer inside the TabNavigator and not the reverse.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. First the drawer, then tabs, then stack. And I need the DrawerOpen inside the first screen of the stack. How did you solve this?

Comment: @JoãoBelo the drawer is a tab navigator. The drawer will include some screens or navigators (stack or tab) and those navigators may have screens or more navigators. Also, you don't need to include the drawer in the stack (as in the example) if you don't have login/register screens.